Setting location as a response header parameter via spring servlet filter in java
I try to add a location in the header of the response for specific API. However, I don't see the location parameter in the response header when I send a request to a related API via Postman. Postman shows only content-type, transfer-encoding, date, keep-alive, and connection parameters but there is no location inside headers.
I use open API code generation and interface classes of APIs are generated. I override the methods in these interface classes in controller classes, so I cannot change method signatures. I am sharing the controller method and servlet filter that I try to send location in headers inside. How can I see the location parameter inside response headers? :
Controller method:
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)  // Sets 201 Created status
public FlightInfo addFlight(final FlightInfo request) {
    // Call the service to add the flight
    final FlightInfo savedFlight = flightService.addFlight(request);

    // Set the flight ID as a request attribute for the filter to use
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = attr.getRequest();
    httpRequest.setAttribute("flightId", savedFlight.getFlightId());

    // Return the FlightInfo response
    return savedFlight;
}

Servlet filter:
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.UUID;

import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

@Component
public class FlightFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    // Proceed with the filter chain to allow the controller to process the request
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    // After the controller has processed the request, check if it’s a POST request to /flight
    if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/flight") && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
        // Retrieve the flight ID from a request attribute
        UUID flightId = (UUID) request.getAttribute("flightId");

        if (flightId != null) {
            // Build the Location URI for the newly created flight
            URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(flightId)
                .toUri();

            // Add the Location header to the response
            response.setHeader("Location", location.toString());
            System.out.println("Location header set: " + location.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Flight ID is null");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI() + ", Method: " + request.getMethod());
    }
}


Are you sure that your filer is invoked at all? Do you see any outputs in logs from your filter? (BTW I would suggest using logger instead of System.out.println). I think that you are missing the annotation @Order and may be your filter is not in use. ALso, since you only want to apply your filter for the path "/flight/*" there is a better way to register your filter using a FilterRegistrationBean. See a good article on the subject here: How to Define a Spring Boot Filter?
